# Ingress Intel App

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, ingress-game

I'm trying to write an app that should show a map:

Anything works but It doesn't show the map. I enabled Javascript and anything in my app but it doesn't work. could you take a look at it?

```
package com.timbremer.iimv;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView wv;
private EditText etlocation;
private Button btclose;
private Button btgo;
private boolean send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    send = false;


    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.ingress.com/intel");
    wv.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);


    etlocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlocation);
    Button btgo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btgo);



    btgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private String location;


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            location = etlocation.getText().toString();

            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
            wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            wv.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if(!send) {
                        view.loadUrl("javascript:{" +
                                "document.getElementById('adress').value='" + location + "';" +
                                "var form = document.getElementsByName('login');" +
                                "form[0].submit();};"
                        );
                        send = true;
                    }
                }


            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here you have a pic of the map: [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uYu9.jpg)
and here is a screenshot of my app: [my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSYq0.jpg)

Comment: what are the errors? Please post the logcat.

Comment: There is nothing in my logcat. The app works but I think something is required to show the map. @Rohan Kandwal

Comment: do you see a white screen?

Comment: your js call is weird. I would wrap those lines in a `function() {}` rather than simply an object.